# Exclude records based on date and other field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a situation I have been working on but can't seems to solve it.

I have employee that record their time in the morning and in the afternoon, so as an example, employee 101 recorded two transaction for the entire day as shown below:

```
    EMPNO  WORKDATE  PAYCODE

    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG
```

So whenever I see the PAYCODE 'REG' I update the table with another PAYCODE called REG1 in the table for this employee for that day, so the now the table looks like this:

```
    EMPNO  WORKDATE  PAYCODE

    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/01/14  REG1
```

So now on 09/02/2014 this employee records two more transactions and the table now looks like this

```
    EMPNO  WORKDATE  PAYCODE

    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/02/14  REG
    101    09/02/14  REG
```

Here comes the problem, if I run my query and update the records with PAYCODE REG1 it duplicate the records on 09/01 again:

```
    EMPNO  WORKDATE  PAYCODE

    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/01/14  REG1
    101    09/02/14  REG
    101    09/02/14  REG
    101    09/02/14  REG1
    101    09/02/14  REG1
```

How do I avoid the duplicates, my queries searches for the REG paycode in the last 7 days, if it finds a REG paycode it's suppose to add REG1 to that day but only if there is not already a REG1 there. So if in a day I could have 2 REG paycodes so I add 2 REG1 but if there is only 1 REG then I only add 1 REG1.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you for your help..

Comment: What does your update query look like, and what is the purpose of adding the REG1 record, is that a manager verification or something?

Comment: I use an interface program that does the REG 1 paycode update,

Comment: Sorry I hit enter too soon, REG1 is for manager verification

Comment: Are you making a time clock?  If so I could suggest some design modifications